# Need I add a multi-column index if I already declares a multi-column unique key in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table that is very frequently used in my website and there are more than 250K records in this table. It is created using this sql statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_favorstocks` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'user id',
  `stockid` varchar(15) NOT NULL COMMENT '.SZ, .SH',
  `added_date` varchar(10) NOT NULL COMMENT '20160101',
  `is_deleted` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0, 1',
  `db_insert_time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `db_update_time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_uid_stockid` (`uid`,`stockid`)
);
```

In the creation statements, a multi column unique key has already been declared but I want to add an index to accelerate the query. Because there are frequently

```
insert into user_favorstocks (uid, stockid, added_date) values ...
```

executed and it is slow(30-60ms and sometimes 100+ms). There are also `update` , `select` operations on the table related to the `uid`, `stockid` field, like

```
update user_favorstocks set is_deleted=1 where uid=xxx and stockid=xxx
```

or

```
select stockid, added_date from user_favorstocks where uid=xxx and is_delete=0
```

Should I add an index like I said? Or does the `unique key` declaration already mean an index creation so that I need not do this?

MySQL version:

5.1.73-log

my.cnf:

```
[client]
#socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
auto-rehash
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
#socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
# following 2:
datadir=/home/data/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
#basedir=/home/mysql/mysql-5.5
#datadir=/home/mysql/mysql-5.5/data
user=mysql
#log-error=/home/mysql/mysql-5.5/logs/error.log
#pid-file=/home/mysql/mysql-5.5/data/mysql.pid
#default-storage-engine=MyISAM

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks;
# to do so, uncomment this line:
symbolic-links=0
#default-character-set=utf8
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
#character-set-database=utf8

#set-variable=wait_timeout=31536000
#set-variable=interactive_timeout=31536000

skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 256M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 256
sort_buffer_size = 1M
read_buffer_size = 1M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 4M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size= 16M
# Try number of CPU's*2 for thread_concurrency
thread_concurrency = 8

# new
# sort_buffer_size = 4M
# read_buffer_size = 4M
# join_buffer_size = 6M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 4M
# myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
# thread_cache_size = 16
# query_cache_size= 16M
# concurrent_insert = 2
# tmp_table_size = 64M
#
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G
# #innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:100M:autoextend
# #innodb_data_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql/data
# innodb_file_per_table = 1
# # 会影响日志写入
# #innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
# #innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
# innodb_io_capacity = 2000
# innodb_large_prefix = 1
# innodb_log_buffer_size = 4198608
# innodb_log_file_size = 256M
# innodb_log_files_in_group = 2

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
#
#skip-networking

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
log-bin=mysql-bin

# binary logging format - mixed recommended
binlog_format=mixed

expire_logs_days = 90

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id       = 1

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 128M
sort_buffer_size = 128M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

# following section:
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

We are currently running this service on a 16GB server and 4 cpu cores, and uses InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the unique key is already an index. You don't need to create another one. Additional indexes actually slow down insert statements. But I wouldn't recommend deleting this index. You obviously need it for your update and select statements.

When your insert statements are slow, you can probably get better performance by tuning other aspects of your server, like the size of your buffer_pool. Post the exact version of your server (the result of `SELECT version();`) and the content of your my.cnf (or my.ini if you're on windows).

Comment: Thanks. I've udpated my question.

Comment: How much memory do you have? And is this a MyISAM or InnoDB table? Consider updating your MySQL version. 5.1 is horribly outdated. I'd recommend at least 5.6. 5.7 is the other option. Do not choose MySQL 8 (this isn't stable yet). Updating is not a blind task, though. The manual has detailed steps.